# Are Questions About Other Planets On Topic?

Tags: discussion

A question has been asked about a strange feature on Mars.

The name of this site **Earth** Science. As interesting as the question is, does the question belong on this site or should it be moved to the Astronomy site?

Is this site solely reserved for questions about Earth? If not, should it be renamed Planetary Science, or Earth & Planetary Science?

Comment: See http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-planetary-science-on-topic . The consensus is that planetary science is on topic. Additionally there have been a poll recently on whether to change the name to reflect this but I can't seem to find it back (the result, if I remember correctly was "no").

Comment: I wasn't aware the question had been asked before, thanks for letting me know. I'm quite happy the way things, even with the name of the site.

Comment: @plannapus the result was indeed no.